# Android select and open file with custom extension

Tags: java, android, file, browser, explorer

Which mimetype is necessary to give the user the opportunity to select a custom file (here: **.oli**) via the filebrowser? I already created one for xml. What do I have to change?

```
Intent chooseFileXML = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(new Helper(FunctionsActivity.this).getPathToAppFolder());
chooseFileXML.setDataAndType(uri, "text/xml");
Intent intentXML = Intent.createChooser(chooseFileXML, getString(R.string.importXMLDatei));
startActivityForResult(intentXML, REQUEST_CODE_IMPORT_XML_FILE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `text/xml` to `*/*`.

BTW, note that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri`, so do not expect apps to pay any attention to that `Uri`.

Comment: How do I check if the selected file has the right type?

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: Nobody but you knows what "the right type" is. Certainly neither the user nor Android nor any other app knows. You will have to examine the contents of the stream and see if it conforms to your expectations or not. You have to do a bit of this anyway, even for an XML file, as XML can be used to describe *lots* of things, and so the user might choose an XML file that happens to not be an XML structure that you can use. Or, the XML file might be corrupt and unparseable.

Comment: I already have that. I think I just cut the extension out from the path of the selected file and do an equals(".oli")

Comment: I got it! Thx a lot!